# How to make on color not overlap other while texture painting?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm developing my first 3d game "My Little Hitler" and I am texture painting my low poly model. As shown in the picture, I want to paint the skin color whithout removing the facial drawing black color... how do I accomplish that?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you can set the blend mode to *multiply*. Since `input_color * 1 = input_color` and `input color * 0 = 0`, painting on white (`1`) will result in the exact color you are painting with, while painting on black (`0`) will result in black.

[image]

But I'd recommend painting from the bottom up, using layers and transparency to minimize destructive editing.

Comment: Layers on texture !!?? I think that's what I'm looking for

Comment: This will only work if the background is white and the foreground is black.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Hence the "your particular case".

Comment: @gandalf3 yes, but this still doesn't explain why it works. I edited you answer to explain it better (you might notice that I basically just used your commented part for this)